# How can I properly display the contents of this stack?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to take a postfix string that has already been converted from infix and evaluate it to display its correct value. Here is my method to parse the postfix string and put digits in a stack (postStack of int value):

```
for (int i = 0; i < post.length(); i++)
            {
                int result;
                if (isdigit(post[i]))
                {
                    int j = post[i] - '0';
                    postStack.push(j);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    token = post[i];   //token = char type;
                    int num2 = postStack.top(); postStack.pop();
                    int num1 = postStack.top(); postStack.pop();
                    result = evaluate(num1, token, num2);   
                    postStack.push(result);
                    continue;
                }
            }
```

And here is the evalutaion method that receives both digits and the operator:

```
int evaluate(int num1, char token, int num2)
{
    int result = 0;
    switch (token)
    {
    case '+': result = num1 + num2;
    case '-': result = num1 - num2;
    case '*': result = num1 * num2;
    case '^': result = (int)(pow(num1, num2) + 0.5);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The output I have been receiving from this when printing has been large negative numbers or zeros. What am I missing here? 
**Output:**

```
1:  2 + 3 * 5
    235*+
    -2147483648

2:  2 + 3 * 5 ^ 6
    2356^*+
    0

3:  2 + 3 - 5 + 6 - 4 + 2 - 1
    23+5-6+4-2+1-
    -2147483647

4:  2 + 3 * (5 - 6) - 4
    2356-*+4-
    0

5:  2 * 3 ^ 5 * 6 - 4
    235^*6*4-
    -2147483648

6:  (2 + 3) * 6 ^ 2
    23+62^*
    -2147483648
```

And here is what I'm using to print the stack:

```
while (!postStack.empty())
                {
                    int itemp = postStack.top(); postStack.pop();
                    cout << itemp;
                }
                cout << endl << endl;
```

Comment: You are missing `break` statement for each of the `cases` which leads to the evaluation of all the cases and you get the result of all four operations at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `switch` is missing a `break` after each `case`. It falls trough and executes every case statement beyond the one that first matched. Meaning in the end you are always calculting the power of `num1` to `num2`. This gives you ridiculous high numbers that don't fit inside an int and you get an overflow, thus the int turns negative.

For example the input "235*+" actually calculates 2 ^ (3 ^ 5) = 2 ^ 243. But an int can only hold values up to 2 ^ 31 - 1.

Comment: Damn, you're right. Can't believe I forgot the breaks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing `break` statement in each of `case` blocks.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int evaluate(int num1, char token, int num2){
    int result = 0;
    switch (token){
        case '+': result = num1 + num2; break;
        case '-': result = num1 - num2; break;
        case '*': result = num1 * num2; break;
        case '^': result = (int)(pow(num1, num2) + 0.5); break;
    }
    return result;
}
int main(){
    string post = "2356^*+";
    stack<int> postStack;
    for (int i = 0; i < post.length(); i++){
        int result;
        if (isdigit(post[i])){
            int j = post[i] - '0';
            postStack.push(j);
        }
        else{
            char token = post[i];   //token = char type;
            int num2 = postStack.top(); postStack.pop();
            int num1 = postStack.top(); postStack.pop();
            result = evaluate(num1, token, num2);   
            postStack.push(result);
        }
    }
    cout << postStack.top() <<endl;
}
```